# How can i add location of customer to admin Online Customers grid?

Tags: customer, magento-1, grid

I have seen There is grid in magento admin for see online customer on store at `Customer->Online Customers`

Now I want to add location here in grid. Is it possible to add location ? If Yes. How to add? I can see ip of customer here.

Comment: Do you mean you need country name corresponding to that IP Address?

Comment: @piyush_systematix Yes. Country and if possible city.

Comment: City or Country of customer seeing website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy file `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Online/Grid.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Online/Grid.php`

Add following code in `_prepareColumns` function before `return` statement.

```
$this->addColumn('location', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Location'),
    'default'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('n/a'),
    'index'     => 'remote_addr',
    'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/customer_online_grid_renderer_location',
    'filter'    => false,
    'sort'      => false
));
```

Create file `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Online/Grid/Renderer/Location.php`

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Online_Grid_Renderer_Location extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $location='N/A';
        try{
            $ipAddress=@inet_ntop($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
            if($ipAddress){
                $data=file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$ipAddress."/json");
                $locationData=json_decode($data,true);
                if(isset($locationData['city'])){
                    $location=$locationData['city'].", ".Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($locationData['country']);
                }
            }            
        }
        catch(Exception $e){}
        return $location;
    }
}
```